# How to override MaxLength, Mask, PromptChar properties of maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, maxlength, maskedtextbox

I created a class that I called [MaskedHexTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27082606/4208024) which inherits from MaskedTetxBox to make it accept only HEX values. Anyway, I need to do the following:

- Give PromptChar a default value of '0' in MaskedHexTextBox, and still be able to change it in the form design
- Give Mask a default value of "\0xAAAA", and still be able to change it in the form design as well
- Use Mask.Length as the default value of MaxLength, I need to use in some calcs, and if I change the Mask after I place the control on the form, I still get the correct Mask length

In general, how can I set a default values for Mask and PromtChar, is there a specific event that I can use to give these properties default values once the control is placed on the form?

I used the class constructor to do this:

```
    public MaskedHexTextBox()
    {
        Mask = "\\0xAAAA";
        PromptChar = '0';
        MaxLength = Mask.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Length;
    }
```

in the Form_load event, I still see that the value for MaxLength is 32767

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(maskedHexTextBox1.MaxLength.ToString());
    }
```

Another issue, suppose that MaxLength was correct, how can I ensure that if the mask is changed from the form design that MaxLength is updated?

Comment: Why not your class's constructor, or as public properties for the containing control to set?

Comment: Even if I make this in constructor, if I change Prefix or Mask, MaxLength will no longer be valid. I don't know how to notify my class with specific properties being changed to recalculate the new MaxLength value. Look at this:

        public MaskedHexTextBox()
        {
            Mask = "\\0xAAAA";
            PromptChar = '0';
            MaxLength = Mask.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Length;
        }
if I change the Mask from form design, how will I ensure that MaxLength is updated?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Ok, I edited the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `Mask` and `PromptChar` properties, if you want the designer to use your custom default values instead of the base ones, then you have to associate them through some helper class (like a `Designer` that overrides `PreFilterProperties`) or to hide the base properties declaring new ones with the same names, like:

```
[Localizable(true), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
[DefaultValue('0')]
public new char PromptChar
{
    get { return base.PromptChar; }
    set { base.PromptChar = value; }
}

[MergableProperty(false), Localizable(true), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.MaskPropertyEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DefaultValue("\\0xAAAA")]
public new string Mask
{
    get { return base.Mask; }
    set { base.Mask = value; }
}
```

For the `MaxLength` property, theoretically you should override it, but the class `MaskedTextBox` provides an empty set accessor that never change the underlying `TextBoxBase.maxLength` field, so you cannot change through the base property.

---

You can however try through **Reflection**, eventually improving your `Mask` property:

```
[MergableProperty(false), Localizable(true), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.MaskPropertyEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DefaultValue("\\0xAAAA")]
public new string Mask
{
    get { return base.Mask; }
    set
    {
        if (base.Mask != value)
        {
            base.Mask = value;
            //FIX_20141127
            //MaxLengthProperty_Set.Invoke(this, new object[] { Mask.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Length });
            SetMaxLength(Mask.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Length);
        }
    }
}

//FIX_20141127
private void SetMaxLength(int value)
{
    if (IsHandleCreated)
    {
        MaxLengthProperty_Set.Invoke(this, new object[] { value});
        MaxLengthField.SetValue(this, value);
    }
}

private static readonly PropertyInfo MaxLengthProperty = typeof(TextBoxBase).GetProperty("MaxLength", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
private static readonly MethodInfo MaxLengthProperty_Set = MaxLengthProperty.GetSetMethod();
//FIX_20141127
private static readonly FieldInfo MaxLengthField = typeof(TextBoxBase).GetField("maxLength", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

If you also want the `MaxLength` property to be visible from the designer, you can add:

```
[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[ReadOnly(true)]
public override int MaxLength
{
    get { return base.MaxLength; }
    set { }
}
```

---

***UPDATE_20141127 (A)***
To address the fact that TextBoxBase.MaxLength seems to not change, you can override OnHandleCreated:

```
//FIX_20141127
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);

    SetMaxLength(Mask.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Length);
}
```

---

***UPDATE_20141127 (B)***
At the following link you can find my (working) test project, containing a minimal MaskedTextBox derived class and a form to display it, along with a button to change the Mask and check MaxLength value.
[Test project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91hoksxaqtd078b/MaskedTextBoxTest.zip?dl=0)

At this other link you can find an already compiled exe for the previous project.
[Test exe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/46vdncq4qs8m3p8/MaskedTextBoxTest.exe?dl=0)

---

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: Actually, what you wrote is kinda new to me, what topics am I supposed to read in Pro c# 5 book? Anyway, none of them is working correctly. PromptChar and Mask are not applied once the component is added to the form, rather the default values from the MaskedTextBox seem to be used i.e. _ for PromptChar and an empty Mask in the form designer. MaxLength is the same, if I use MessageBox to show me the MaxLength value at startup, I see 32767.. not even invoking MaxLengthProperty_Set.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, please. I just updated the code to force-set the value of the backing field. It is a Reflection hack as the property/setter and shouldn't be taken as permanently trustable (we don't know what MS can change in the future), but at least updates the field value as originally expected. Take into account that the backing field is a .NET thing, whereas the real UI control receive the value through an internal Windows Message (EM_LIMITTEXT) and in fact is limiting the text box length.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the EM_LIMITTEXT message gets sent only if the control has been already created (IsHandleCreated returning true) and only if the hidden field maxLength's value changes, so you should delay setting Mask or at least delay setting maxLength until the control gets created (you can override OnHandleCreated).

Comment: It is still not working. Adding the control to the From, it doesn't take the default values of PromptChar and Mask. This in turn results in MaxLength becoming 0 instead of 6. If I change the Mask from the Form design, then it takes it, and `SetMaxLength(Mask.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Length);` is executed twice, once in the OnHandleCreated and another in Mask reflection. PromptChar is always _ regardless of what it is set to in the Form design.

Comment: Yes: SetMaxLength is executed twice, but takes effect only when IsHandleCreated is true, that is not the case during the initial assignment of Mask. However it is working for me, so I'm going to post my test code for you to try yourself.

Comment: Hello. Have you tested the sample project I provided?

Comment: No, I did not see it at that time. I will, of course.

Comment: Now I know why it was not working.. My project doesn't have whatevername.Designer.cs for my component, I only have MaskedTextBox.cs class file with public class MaskedHexTextBox : MaskedTextBox, I don't even know how this file get's generated and when it gets generated by the IDE. I just added a class and wrote what I needed, turned out I should have added a new component in the first place...

Comment: Well, the whatever.Designer.cs file is not mandatory. If you use the "Add class" wizard and choose "User Control", VS will create the whatever.cs, whatever.Designer.cs and whatever.resx files together at once. The only purpose of whatever.Desginer.cs is to separate code logic from child UI components and UI initialization code; you can still write everything inside one .cs file, but in that case you can not take advantage of the designer facility directly over your custom component.